# Strapi 4, POST data with relation field

Tags: strapi

I am trying to create a new `event` (my content type name) trough the strapi rest API.

My payload:

```
{
        title: "Event1",
        description: "Somedescription",
        date: "SomeDate",
        store: 3 //this is the relation id
      },
```

According to the documentation it should be correct... the event is created but the relation is not being filled, it shows as empty...

my events schema:

```
....

"store": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "api::store.store",
      "inversedBy": "events"
    }

.....
```

I took a look at the strapi log and it does not seem to be doing any try to record the relation because the sql looks like this:

```
{
  method: 'insert',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [
    2022-05-21T15:14:47.404Z,
    2022-05-30T16:00:00.000Z,
    'h',
    2022-05-21T15:14:47.403Z,
    'h',
    2022-05-21T15:14:47.404Z
  ],
  __knexQueryUid: 'ZimE1XysRQZdZzz07fOQt',
  sql: 'insert into "events" ("created_at", "date", "description", "published_at", "title", "updated_at") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning "id"',
  returning: 'id'
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having exact same issue. I'm trying to format JSON (in client JS save code) to save a record with a link to another record. I'm searching and can't find the answer.

Comment: @Locohost hey bro yes, I fixed it! let me back home tonight and tell you how